# Custom XMPP IQ in iOS XMPP Framework

Tags: ios, xcode, xmppframework

I want to send custom IQ using xmpp framework in iOS for the following XML:

```
<iq type="get">
<questionrequest xmlns="xyz" group="abc">
</questionrequest>
</iq>
```

I used the below code in iOS:

```
XMPPIQ *iq = [[XMPPIQ alloc] initWithType:@"get"];
DDXMLElement *query = [DDXMLElement elementWithName:@"questionrequest" xmlns:@"xyz" group:@"abc"];
[iq addChild:query];
[[[self appDelegate] xmppStream] sendElement:iq];
NSLog(@"iq: %@", [iq prettyXMLString]);
```

It is giving an error when I add group="abc"> part in DDXMLElement *query. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it worked by using the below code:

```
XMPPIQ *iq = [[XMPPIQ alloc] initWithType:@"get"];
    DDXMLElement *query = [DDXMLElement elementWithName:@"questionrequest" xmlns:@"naseebprofile"];
    [query addAttributeWithName:@"group" stringValue:@"Tastes"];
    [iq addChild:query];
    [[[self appDelegate] xmppStream] sendElement:iq];
```

Comment: I have created an application in iOS and connected & fetched users from xmpp and able to get offline messages too.Now i need to fetch conversations of a particular user using XEP-0313, How to implement XEP-0313

Comment: @MaheshNarla You can do it by querying against specific JID i.e. Querying for all messages to/from a particular JID.