# iOS - XMPP with WebRTC for realtime video call or chat

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, xmpp, webrtc

I have searched the whole web but did not get any document for passing the **[XMPP](https://xmpp.org/about/technology-overview.html)** `IQ` to WebRTC. Also I see is the XMPP **[`Jingle`](https://xmpp.org/about/technology-overview.html#jingle)** class, but cannot find any document for integrate this.

Can someone help me with setting up a two-way video call using XMPP and WebRTC? By providing a working sample of `Objective-C` code?

I have tried:
Checking https://github.com/YK-Unit/AppRTCDemo and many other Github projects.

Comment: This question is too broad and a request for an off-site resource (sample code), which is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I tried to improve your Question. Check & fix anything wrong. Also try using this site's search. For example does this **[Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22804932/2057709)** have useful info?

Answer (score 0):

Are you want to support different platforms to get live video streaming?

So, i have a very good experience with https://www.nanocosmos.de/ library.
It's supports iOS, Android and Web. Has demo applications and trial period.

About documentation:

XMPP Framework: https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/IntroToFramework

It's very good documented.

WebRTC Native Code:
https://webrtc.org/native-code/ios/

It's contains all information about WebRTC.